# Hacer que un textarea dentro se un model-content se adapte al contenido que posee model-content

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo la problematica siguiente, me gustaria saber como podría hacer que este modal adapte su altera dependiendo del contenido que posea la clase modal-content. He intentado usar css y Javascript pero no obtengo los resultados que deseo

Si preguntan, eso se debe hacer en onload, es decir al cargarse, porque tengo una tabla que le manda los datos

```
function getHtml(valor){

            var idAcceso = $('#Id_acceso').val();

            datos= JSON.stringify(valor);

            htmlSemana="<tr>";

            //valida si la clase esta activa
            if(valor[0][18] == "Si"){
                moment(valor[0][10],'h:m a').format('h:m a')
                htmlSemana+=`
                <td>${moment(valor[0][6],'h:mm a').format('h:mm a')} ${moment(valor[0][7],'h:mm a').format('h:mm a')}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href='register.php?clase=${valor[0][0]}'>
                        <small>Registrarse(${valor[0][10]}/${valor[0][11]})</small>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>${valor[0][1]}
                        <i 
                        id='question'
                        data-toggle='modal'
                        data-target='#ver_clase'
                        style='cursor:pointer; color:purple; margin-left: 2px;'
                        onclick='mostrar2(${datos});'
                        class='fa fa-question-circle' aria-hidden='true' style="color:purple;"
                    >
                    </i>
                </td>`;
                
                //valida si la clase no posee instructor
                if(valor[0][15] == null){

                    htmlSemana+=`<td>Instructor no Asignado</td>`;
    
                }else{

                    htmlSemana+=`<td>${valor[0][8]} ${valor[0][9]}</td>`;
                }

                htmlSemana+=`<td>${valor[0][3]}</td><td>${valor[0][4]}</td>`;

            }else{

                htmlSemana+="<td colspan='6'>Clase Cancelada</td>";
            }
            if(idAcceso > 2){
                htmlSemana+=`
                <td>
                    <a 
                        href='${valor[0]['url_grabada']}' target="_blank"
                    >
                    Link</a>
                </td>`;  
            }
            if(idAcceso > 2){
                htmlSemana+=`
                <td>
                    <i 
                        id='edit'
                        data-toggle='modal'
                        data-target='#seleccionar_clasefinal'
                        style='cursor:pointer;'
                        onclick='mostrar(${datos});'
                        class='fa fa-cog' aria-hidden='true'
                    >
                    </i>
                </td>`;  
            }

            htmlSemana+=`</tr>`;
        

            return htmlSemana;

        }
```

Se comunica con esta función llamada mostrar2

```
    function mostrar2(datos){

        datos = datos[0];
        console.log(datos);
       
        document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = datos['nombre_clase'];
        $("#descripcion_clase").val(datos['descripcion']);
    }
```

Y esta funcion pasa los datos al modal ubicado en ModalVerClase.tpl. El cual es este

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ver_clase">  
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:purple;">
                <div id="titulo" style="color: white;"></div>
                <button 
                type="button" 
                class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" 
                aria-label="Close" 
                id="close" 
                name="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="autoheight" readonly style="width:100%;" id="descripcion_clase"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Así es como sale el modal si quieren visualizarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No funciono, modal content es el que parece ajustar el tamaño

Comment: veo que tienes definido un alto al modal en: <div class="modal-content" style="height:45%;">, será este el inconveniente?

Comment: No, lo quite y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: estás usando smarty?

Comment: Si, estoy usando smarty

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea#descripcion_clase {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 40px) !important;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Asi seria para un "margen" de 20 pixels. No es un margen real. He tenido que simularlo con valores que he asignado a los estilos que me ha hecho falta cambiar.

No se si te funcionaria porque no se si tienes ya algun CSS que no nos cuentes. De impedir su funcionamiento estaria bien que lo agregases (el que ya tiene el caso) a la pregunta.

Probablemente haya una mejor manera de hacerlo pero para saberlo necesito el CSS.